# Auto-create service instance in AngularJS (no lazy-load)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, dependency-injection

I've created a service that needs to listen for `$route` events. I'm setting listeners with `$rootScope.$on()`. My service looks like this:

```js
application.factory('myListener', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', myListener.onChangeStart);
    return {
        onChangeStart: function() {
            // Do something.
        }
    };
}]);
```

It works OK, but I have to inject instance of this service at least once somewhere in my application in order for listener to attach itself.

Is there a way to force-create the instance without injecting it somewhere?

Maybe you could recommend a better way to structure this service?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the service, but rather some code that runs when the application starts, then you should put it into a run block:

```js
application.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() {
        // Do something.
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`angular.injector().get('myListener');` should give you the instance of the service.